# Alternative to list to store large dataframe?

Tags: python

I have a multiple files in a folder. Looping through the folder I use pd.read_csv() to read the files and store it in the list. After storing all the files I use pd.concat(list) to get the single dataframe. But, my concern is list uses the memory to store the data. When the dataframe is huge list consumes lots of memory. Is there any other alternative to list I can use to store the data

Comment: Can you post your code? do you only want file names or some other data? And how many files we are talking about?

Comment: Google: Dask https://dask.org/